# How to integrate ajax to Wordpress theme?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to use ajax in wordpress

I have two files, php and js

this is my php code
 `combo_check-out.php`

```
function iRange($first, $last, $format = 'm/d/Y' ) { 
        $dates = array();
        $current = strtotime($first);
        $i=1;
        while( $i <= $last ) { 
            $dates[] = date($format, $current);
            $current = strtotime('+1 day', $current);
            $i++;
        }

        $time = date("m/d/Y",$current);
        return $time;
    }

if($_REQUEST)
{
    $id     = $_REQUEST['parent_id'];
    ?>


    <select name="check-out"  id="check-out-date">
        <option value="<?php echo iRange($id, 1, $format = 'm/d/Y' ) ?>">"1 Day (Same Day)"</option>
        <option value="<?php echo iRange($id, 2, $format = 'm/d/Y' ) ?>">"2 Days"</option>
        <option value="<?php echo iRange($id, 3, $format = 'm/d/Y' ) ?>">"3 Days"</option>
        <option value="<?php echo iRange($id, 4, $format = 'm/d/Y' ) ?>">"4 Days"</option>
    </select>   

<?php}?>
```

and here it is my js code
`combo_checkout_iRange.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
    $('#check-in-date').change(function(){
        $('#check-out-date-wrap').fadeOut();
        $('#loader').show();
        $.post("combo_check-out.php", {
            parent_id: $('#check-in-date').val(),
        }, function(response){
            setTimeout("finishAjax('check-out-date-wrap', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
        });
        return false;
    });
});

//JQuery to hide Loader and return restults
function finishAjax(id, response){
  $('#loader').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
} 

function alert_id()
{
    if($('#check-out-date').val() == '')
    alert('Please select a sub category.');
    else
    alert($("#check-out-date").val());
    return false;
}
```

they work fine outside wordpress

how to integrate them in wordpress theme

**Note:** this should work in post type called "meetings"
so this is what i wrote on `function.php`

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", function() {

     if (is_single()) {
        if (get_post_type() == 'meetings')
        {
            wp_enqueue_script('combo_checkout_iRange', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/combo_checkout_iRange.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' ,true);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: See my answer to a similar question... Properly utilising ajax in wordpress requires a few more steps than you have... http://stackoverflow.com/a/28966067/4572608

Comment: thank you @danbahrami I understand what you wrote, but I can't implement it in my case .. would u explain more what to write in ajax function .. and thnx again for your help

Comment: why can't you implement it? The issue is not with your Ajax function, it is that you are working on a platform that has it's own set of rules. If you want to implement Ajax on Wordpress you just need to follow the steps in that answer.

Comment: The quick solution would be to use a more defined path to the PHP page. The solution that @danbahrami suggested localizes the script paths so that you don't have to expressly define the path to the PHP file you are trying to load, but if you fully qualify the PHP path to your theme directory where the PHP actually is, it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First step**

the url you need to hit that is :

```
<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>
```

now there are couple of method to get this into the js . that is your "ajaxurl"

**Second Step**

with the url , you need to pass a action like :

> url?action=your_ajax_hit

in jquery , it would be like :

```
$.ajax({
 url : ajaxurl+'?action=your_ajax_hit',
 type : 'post'
.....
.....
.....
});
```

**Third Step**

into the functions.php you can add

```
add_action("wp_ajax_your_ajax_hit", "your_function_name");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_your_ajax_hit", "your_function_name");

function your_function_name(){

   // your code 

  wp_die();
}
```

you can see its

> wp_ajax_  your_ajax_hit

thats it

please read this : http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: thanks a lot for your help.. But I did many updates in this code [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174776/the-wordpress-ajax-request-returns-0)is my last update, but my problem now is that my ajax request returns "0"

Comment: Yes, I did, it works now :) my problem was in the location of Ajax handler
Thnak you :)