# Ajax custom function return 0 in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

> Here is my test.php page where I have trying to use ajax function to get data in WordPress and working on custom pages. There is no error but it returns 0 on console. Please help me out

**script function to call page to get the values from database**
**test.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

                                <div>
                                    
                                    <table width="100%" style="background-color: #0066ff; color: white;">
                                        <tr width="75%">
                                            <td>
                                                <h2>Notification</h2>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="15%">
                                                <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true" id="demo"></i>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>

                                </div>
                           

<script>
load();
function load() 
{   
    var baseurl = '<?php echo site_url();?>';   
    var ajaxurl = baseurl + '/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/fetch.php';   
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php");?>';
    
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:ajaxurl,
        success:function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

**fetch.php**

```
    <?php
     
    global $wpdb;
    
    $data=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `notification` WHERE to_id = 1154");
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        // code...
        $sender_id= $value->from_id;
        $message= $value->meassage;
        $sender_name = $value->from_name;
    
    echo json_encode($message);
    
    }
    
    
     ?>
```

Comment: There's a typo in your code. You set "**$message**" and you echo **$meassage**

Comment: there is an additional "a" in $message I also removed that but it doesn't work the result came same it returns 0

Comment: please echo a constant value like `echo 'hello';` to see if the result is stil 0.

Comment: add `exit;` at the end of the php code

Comment: make sure you've used `wp_ajax_nopriv` when adding the action

Comment: I also tried echo but it doesn't work sir any other suggestion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The WordPress Ajax request returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174776/the-wordpress-ajax-request-returns-0)

Comment: are you using `add_action` to register the ajax request in wordpress ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `add_action()` in WordPress to register an ajax response function.

See https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins and https://wpmudev.com/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/.

Comment: Thanks a loot sir and it's help me out and now I'm suggesting the best way is using hocks in wordpress for using ajax request.